# How to write a proof to prove convergence of sequences?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, proof-writing

> Prove that if $(x_n) \to 2$, then $(1/x_n) \to 1/2$

My main questions is that I am unsure what counts as formal proof for proving converging on sequences. I will use the above question as an example. Here is what my thought process is when I did the rough work. I am not sure however, how to turn this into a formal, well-written proof.

$$|\frac{1}{x_n} - \frac{1}{2}| = |\frac{2-x_n}{2x_n}|$$

So clearly, we need to bound $x_n$ below so that it does not go to $0$. I observe that since $(x_n) \to 2$, this means that after some $N_1$, all the terms of $x_n$ will be stuck inside some $\epsilon$ neighbourhood. For simplicity, I just choose $\epsilon = 1$. So applying definition of convergence, for all $n \ge N_1$, $|x_n - 2| < 1$.

Note that the above means that for $n \ge N_1$, $|x_n| > 1$. Next, use the below to get $N_2$. $$|\frac{2-x_n}{2x_n}| \le \frac{|2-x_n|}{2} < \epsilon \implies |2-x_n| = |x_n - 2| < 2 \epsilon$$. So we have that for all $n \ge N_2$, $|x_n - 2| < 2 \epsilon$.

Hence, taking $N = \max \{N_1, N_2 \}$

Comment: You should choose $N = \max\{N_1, N_2\}$

Comment: @hff1 Yes, thank you. I've edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You managed to use a lot of inequality tricks you may have just learned, and that is great. Your logic chain is correct. However it seems you've mixed two $\varepsilon$'s unintentionally. Let's break it down.

> Q1. How can we even talk about $\frac{1}{x_n}$ if we often have $x_n=0$? You've noticed that $x_n$ will be away from $0$ when $n$ is big enough so the first question is not of our concern. There is no issue with this observation. Formally speaking:

Since $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n=2$, there exists $N_1>0$ such that whenever $n>N_1$, one has $|x_n-2|<1$, which implies that $1<x_n<3$.

> Q2. After getting rid of $1/0$, how can we show that $\frac{1}{x_n} \to \frac{1}{2}$ formally?

Notice that

$$
\left|\frac{1}{x_n}-\frac{1}{2}\right| =\left|\frac{2-x_n}{2x_n}\right|.
$$

Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=2$, for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $N_2>0$ such that whenever $n>N_2$, one has $|2-x_n|<\varepsilon$.

Put $N=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$, when $n>N$, one has $|2-x_n|<\varepsilon$ and $\frac{1}{|2x_n|}<\frac{1}{2}$, and therefore

$$
\left|\frac{1}{x_n}-\frac{1}{2}\right| =\left|\frac{2-x_n}{2x_n}\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.
$$

This proves that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{x_n}=\frac{1}{2}$.

---

Let's review your attempt. You try to form a proof by answering Q1 and Q2. However, the $\varepsilon$ in Q1 has nothing to do with Q2, but you did not distinguish them, which makes your proof confusing.

In Q1, we **have already known** that $|x_n-2|<\varepsilon$ will hold whenever $n$ is big enough for all $\varepsilon>0$, so we have infinitely many $\varepsilon$ to pick but putting $\varepsilon=1$ makes our life easy enough.

In Q2, we **have to show** that $\left|\frac{1}{x_n}-\frac{1}{2}\right|<\varepsilon$ holds for all $\varepsilon>0$ whenever $n$ is big enough. You need to use $|x_n-2|$ being small enough to deduce that $\left|\frac{1}{x_n}-\frac{1}{2}\right|$ will be small enough. Therefore 1) you can't mix it with your previous $\varepsilon=1$ or otherwise this $\varepsilon$ comes out of nowhere which is still not good; 2) your proof should end with $\left|\frac{1}{x_n}-\frac{1}{2}\right|$ being small enough instead of $|x_n-2|$ being small enough.

Comment: This breakdown is exactly what I was hoping for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

By definition $ (x_n) \to 2 \iff \forall \epsilon>0, \exists N | n>N \implies  |x_n-2|<\epsilon$.

$ |x_n-2|<\epsilon\implies 2-\epsilon < x_n<2+\epsilon$

$\implies \frac{1}{2+\epsilon}< \frac{1}{x_n}<\frac{1}{2-\epsilon}$

$\implies (\frac{1}{2}) (1-\epsilon/2+...)< \frac{1}{x_n}< (\frac{1}{2})(1+\epsilon/2 - ...)$

$\implies -\epsilon/4 +... < \frac{1}{x_n}-\frac{1}{2}< \frac{\epsilon}{4}-...$

$\implies |\frac{1}{x_n}-\frac{1}{2}|<\frac{\epsilon}{4}$

So you can reuse the same $N$ so long as $\epsilon/2<1$.